# Transition Function for controls c# just like CSS

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Is there a way to implement a CSS like property for example:

```
    .TextBox {
        Height: 10;
        BackgroundColor: red;
        Transition: all 2s;
    }

    .TextBox:Hover {
        Height: 20;
        BackgroundColor: bluel
    }
```

if you are familiar with CSS in webdeveloping you will notice that the height and the background color will transition to the :Hover event after 2seconds

So my point is how can i implement this kind of class in c#

Or is there already a framework for this or a library to this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose use WPF which will allow you to do a lot more in areas of look and feel. That's assuming you are working on winforms application